# Php MongoDB Exception:not authorized on db to execute command { update:

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following code

```
$bulkWrite=new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$update = ['$set' => ['name' => 'Smith', age: 35, profession => 'pilot']];
$options = array('multi' => false, 'upsert' => false);
$bulkWrite->update($filter, $options);
$mongoConn->executeBulkWrite('MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

The code returns the error:

```
Exception:not authorized on db to execute command { update:
```

What is the issue?

Comment: Please don't [repost this question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273537/catchable-fatal-error-argument-2-passed-to-mongodb-driver-managerexecutebulkw), There was already comment there why you self Q&A is not needed here. You're using the wrong driver.

Comment: What do you mean "wrong driver"? What is better?

Comment: Well you were actually [given a link](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) before you deleted your previous posting of this very same thing. And the reason the post was put on hold before was 1. "Typo", so we don't need common Q&A for that. 2. As referenced, you don't use `MongoDB\Driver` **directly** unless you really know what you are doing, ( which is essentially writing another 'high level driver'). You general application needs to be using the other namespace as referenced. Please read it, because all the links are there to explain.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code I found that the issue is in the name of the collection.
If we have before:

```
$DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://dbName:dbPassword";
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
$mongoConn = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );
```

Then after we need to have the correct reference to the dbName:

```
$bulkWrite=new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$update = ['$set' => ['name' => 'Smith', age: 35, profession => 'pilot']];
$options = array('multi' => false, 'upsert' => false);
$bulkWrite->update($filter, $options);
$mongoConn->executeBulkWrite('dbName.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```